# Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll'

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have two published environment, one for test and one for live.
my published project works in test env. without any issue, but as soon as I deploy it on live env.
I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2021-06-08 16:45:34,415 455867ms ysomeController MoveNext           - System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNINativeManagedWrapperX64.SNIInitialize(IntPtr pmo)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..ctor() in H:...\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 19
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNILoadHandle..cctor() in H:...\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParserSafeHandles.cs:line 17
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..cctor() in H:...\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 177
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser..ctor(Boolean MARS, Boolean fAsynchronous) in H:...\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:line 38
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in H:...\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:line 1831
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in
```

Updated: I also should mention that Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64.dll exists in \bin after deployment.

Comment: Please try to Nuget package update  **Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.x64** and Update VS and OS latest version.

Comment: Double check your application configuration (if using IIS, that you're actually running as a web application) to verify the `bin` folder is actually searched for binaries.

Comment: This is happening to me to me and so far, no suggested solutions work.
It is part of my installed NuGet packages for the entire package, but I don't see the DLL under Web\BIN folder and I cannot manually add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was about the I/O of published folder.
By granting the folder to related user the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was running a rest api local on Windows via parallels on my mac. I also saw the dlls in bin. So I checked the full path, which was: \\Mac\Home\Documents\Projects... I figured maybe that path is not recognised. So I copied my project to a different folder directly on my parallels Windows: C:\users\ncu\projects... After that everything worked.

**In other words**: Check the full path to your dll's

Answer (score 0):

Created my project as a stand-alone service. When the service started on the host, I would get the same error. Then I realized that the two DLL files (Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll and sni.dll) were sitting in the Publish folder along with the Application file. I copied the two files into the same directory as the service application file on the host server. Now the service runs!